# Need to manipulate data in excel 2016 from one column to many columns

Tags: microsoft-excel-2016

I have hundreds of contacts in a single column in xlsx 2016.

[image: link to screenshot of data]

What I need to do is bring all the data into individual columns as shown below

Col 1: Company Name, Col 2: Address, Col 3: Reg Head, Col 4: Tel Col 5 Fax: Col 7: Email

To throw a spanner in the works some addresses spread over 2 rows.

Comment: Welcome to Super User. New members commonly mistake this for a service site where we will do the work. It is a Q&A community where specific questions are asked after you have attempted something and get stuck. Please add details of what you have tried so far, including scripts, code or formulas, and we will try to help. If you need more info about asking questions, check out ***[ask]*** in the ***[help]***.

Comment: Thanks Charlie, What I have tried so far is adding color to each similar cell (all email cells red etc.) and then filtering on color, then copying all emails into one column.  It hasn't worked real well as some contacts have emails and others don't.  So when company name is copied into column 1 and emails into column 2 they don't line up.

Answer (score 0):

As you have found out, because the data is not standardized, it is going to be difficult to find an easy solution. This means there will likely be lots of manual manipulation to get it the way you want it. We could not possibly write a macro or formula to account for all the scenarios.

One way to do this is to select and cut the cells under the company name. Then select the cell to the right of the company name and paste using the `Transpose` option.

I would suggest inserting a column for `Address 2`. Then for the companies without a second address line, you will insert a cell and shift your data to the right.